# Specify the value where colours change in the key

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, colors, openair

I am plotting pollution data, and have multiple plots with the same axis on a colour scheme.

Because there are a few high peaks in the data, it's throwing the rest of the colour chart off where most of the key is one colour, and the rest of the colour spectrum is squashed down to the lowest values.

Easiest to see a picture - example of two of the axes here

[image]

How can I change it so that the colour spectrum is more evenly spaced out? If I try to force it through `limits = c(0, 1.0)`, it turns my whole plot basically one colour.

Comment: Use `log(var)` to fill the colors? But to get a better answer, please read [MCVE] and [edit] your question to include data and code.